# How do I add a console output window in java?

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to put a console output window in a runnable jar file. I looked up a way that would work for me but I also would need to know how to get that into my main file as this one has its own package etc.

```
package newbuttonthing;

import java.util.Date;

public class clock {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       // Instantiate a Date object
       Date date = new Date();

       // display time and date using toString()
       System.out.println(date.toString());
   }
}
```

The window should just have to show up in a little bar (1 line?) at the bottom of the window i will clarify if needed (post my code and indicate where in the window it needs to be).

Comment: Are you asking how to get the characters written to `System.out`?

Comment: Anything would work as long as it prints it out somewhere that someone can see it.

Comment: For SO questions, you need to ask something quite _specific_ (like, how to get access to the data written to `System.out`), rather than open ended like _design me a GUI application with a log window_.  We're here to help, but you've got to meet us half-way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
public static void setOutput(final JLabel label) {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            char c = (char) b;
            if (c == '\n' || c == '\r') {
                label.setText("");
            } else {
                label.setText(label.getText() + c);
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

Then every time you call `System.out.print` or `System.out.println` it will display the latest line on your label.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that he is asking a GUI window that displays the date and time.  For this to work you will need a thread to periodically update the GUI window for the current date and time.